# Can't call a function from a separate file

Tags: php, function, request, include, undefined

I'm trying to run a function that's inside an included file. The file get's included properly but I still get a *undefined function* error. Tried everything and nothing seems to work. Here's a simplified version of my code...

**File functions.php**

```
<?php function myFunction($foo){ echo $foo; } ?>
```

**File index.php**

```
<?php include('functions.php'); $string = "Hello, world!"; myFunction($string); ?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function myFunction()
>   in /functions.php on line 1

I tried with include, include_once, request, request_once and even creating a class with a public function but nothing works. The file is being properly included because if I added an echo at the beginning of functions.php and it displays properly on index.php. Also, there is no error in my function because if I run it from the functions.php file it works like a charm. The problem is that index.php isn't recognizing myFunction() as a defined function. Could it be a problem with the php.ini file? The include works so that can't be it.

How can I call myFunction($foo) from index.php?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are `index.php` and `functions.php` in the same directory?

Comment: I assume you mean `require, require_once` and not `request, request_once`

Comment: The code you show us works just fine. So there is something else that you have not told us that is causing your problem

Comment: This error: `Call to undefined function myFunction() in /functions.php on line 1` .... is saying you are trying to call that function from `functions.php`... odd. Are you sure you have pasted to us EXACTLY the content of `functions.php`?

Comment: RiggsFolly They are both in the same directory. The include works properly as I stated, the functions aren't being recognized cross-file.
Yes, you are correct: require and require_once, not request and request_once.

Randall, I wrote a simplified example that emulates the error. As you see, both files only contain 1 line of code.

Could it be something that isn't configured in the PHP.ini file? Is there something that needs to be enabled for functions to work through includes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to fix it. In the original file I was calling the include via a complete URL. I wrote it with an absolute URL and it worked. Must be a local server thing.

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score -1):

It worked, please make sure that you put functions.php and index.php in the same location. Then do the following...

> functions.php

```
<?php

 function showmsg($msg=''){
    echo 'Hi' . ' ' . $msg;
}

?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';

$str = 'Nilesh';
showmsg($str);

?>
```

Comment: Why change everything about the OP's code when it works exectly as it was written by the OP

Comment: @RiggsFolly, as this is not the answer. Can be down voted.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I am trying to be a nice guy! But you feel free if you feel strongly enough about it

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am not the down voter though. But Nilesh has mentioned nothing new with his answer.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Correct, its a horrible answer. It will either get downvoted or completely ignored. I am just ignoring it